# How do I specify fallback fonts in Java2D/Graphics2D

Tags: java, fonts, java-2d, graphics2d, fallback

I'm using `g.drawString(str, x, y)` to draw a String with a `Graphics2D` object `g`. The current font of `g` does not cover all the characters of `str` (I have e.g. Chinese chars in there). On Mac OS X, a fallback font seems to be automatically used, but not on Windows, where black square outlines appear instead of the wanted characters.

- Why is the behavior different depending on the platform?
- How do I specify a fallback font (or several fallback fonts) in case of missing characters?

(For instance, one of the nice fonts [there](http://www.clearchinese.com/resources/fonts.htm).)

**Update/More Info**

So, the original font that doesn't support all characters is not one of the JVM's [logical fonts](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/intl/faq.jsp#font-selection), but is a bundled font that comes with my app and was obtained with `Font.createFont()`. So, adding fonts to the JRE's `lib/fonts/fallback` folder doesn't work here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We could attribute string to switch font on "bad" symbols and use `Graphics2D.drawString(AttributedCharacterIterator iterator, int x, int y)` to render result. *Advantage*: this will work with any font. *Drawback*: without some sort of caching of intermediate objects this will work slower and dirtier.

So, i suggest using [`AttributedString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/AttributedString.html) with main font attribute on whole string:

```
AttributedString astr = new AttributedString(text);
astr.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, mainFont, 0, textLength);
```

and with fallback font on specific parts:

```
astr.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, fallbackFont, fallbackBegin, fallbackEnd);
```

The rendering itself:

```
g2d.drawString(astr.getIterator(), 20, 30);
```

The result (Physical "Segoe Print" as main font, logical "Serif" as fallback):

[image]

Complete supposed-to-be-SSCCE code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import java.text.AttributedString;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FontTest extends JFrame {

    public FontTest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(new TestStringComponent());
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new FontTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class TestStringComponent extends JComponent {

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.setColor(getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        g.setColor(getForeground());

        Font mainFont = new Font("Segoe Print", Font.PLAIN, 25);
        Font fallbackFont = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 25);

        String s = "Test 漢鼎繁古印 Test 漢鼎繁古印 Test";

        g2d.drawString(createFallbackString(s, mainFont, fallbackFont).getIterator(), 20, 30);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 40);
    }

    private AttributedString createFallbackString(String text, Font mainFont, Font fallbackFont) {
        AttributedString result = new AttributedString(text);

        int textLength = text.length(); 
        result.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, mainFont, 0, textLength);

        boolean fallback = false;
        int fallbackBegin = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            boolean curFallback = !mainFont.canDisplay(text.charAt(i));
            if (curFallback != fallback) {
                fallback = curFallback;
                if (fallback) {
                    fallbackBegin = i;
                } else {
                    result.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, fallbackFont, fallbackBegin, i);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it also not works whith modifications of `fontconfig.properties`. Usual way is to add custom font file to fallback sequence. Needed lines are: `filename.Yourfont=YOURFONT.TTF` and `allfonts.yourfont=Yourfont`; then add `yourfont` to `sequence.fallback` list. I planned to extend answer with details, but unfortunately, it works only for standard *logical* fonts. Maybe some more fontconfig-magic needed, but it is out of my skills and experience. I apologize for unuseful answer.

Comment: I've removed wrong solution. At least, workaround does it's purpose.